# Yahoo Mail ID not working for email services

Tags: apex-email-service, email2case

I am using email services and created a custom code. It works for all google or any personal domain.
But the issue occur as when I use yahoo email address , I am unable to receive. Is there any restriction in salesforce.

Comment: yahoo and DMARC - spam prevention - check out https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000193813

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the test email deliverability option in Salesforce?

URL: https://***instance***.salesforce.com/email-admin/testEmailDeliverability.apexp

> Salesforce sends email from many different IP addresses. The number of addresses depends on your data center and appears on the Test Deliverability page. If your organization blocks any of these IP addresses, users might not receive all email sent from Salesforce. You can check whether your organization is receiving email from every Salesforce IP address.

More info [here](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_test_email_delivery.htm)

Comment: I have already tested that and it is working fine regarding the email deliverability . Only the email coming from yahoo fails rest all works fine

Comment: Can you test the deliverability when using a workflow notification for example? Also post your code.